# Java dynamically invoke method which is dynamically attached (by dynamic proxy) on an object

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, invoke, dynamic-proxy

I have a method which has arguments an object instance and a string which represents the name of a method, with the following signature:

```
Object executeDynamicMethod(Object instance, String methodName);
```

I can easily execute the method by name by using reflection, something like the following:

```
Method methodToExecute = instance.getClass().getMethod(methodName...);
methodToExecute.invoke(); ...
```

However, what happens when the instance is a proxied one, and the method is running though an invocation handler? Then the **instance** object Class here has not the method and I can not get it and invoke it.
Additionally, I don't want to use *Proxy.getInvocationHandler(instance)* because sometimes the instance is proxied, but sometimes not, and I don't want to spoil it with *if* statements.

Thus, is there any way to invoke a method by its name on an instance without having to retrieve the method from the class first?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case i have implemented a Proxy that delegates to a „real“ object (For caching reasons). But sometimes the delegate was also Proxy.  However, in this Proxy a have to invoke sometimes a method via reflection on a class and sometimes on a proxy (like your problem).
I hope this small example is self-explanatory.

```
public class ProxyTest {

interface A {
    public void doit();
}

static class B implements A {
    @Override
    public void doit() {
        System.out.println("I am a B");
    }
}

static class ProxyOfA implements InvocationHandler {
    private A delegate;

    ProxyOfA(A delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (delegate instanceof Proxy) {
            //This is a proxy
            InvocationHandler invocationHandler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(delegate);
            invocationHandler.invoke(delegate, method, args);
        } else {
            // This is not a proxy
            method.invoke(delegate, args);
        }
        System.out.println("Proxy of Proxy invoked");
        return null;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //instantiate targets
    A b = new B();
    A proxy = (A) Proxy.newProxyInstance(A.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { A.class },
            new InvocationHandler() {
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    System.out.println("I am a Proxy");
                    return null;
                }
            });

    //instantiate proxies
    A proxyOfb = (A) Proxy.newProxyInstance(A.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { A.class }, new ProxyOfA(b));
    A proxyOfproxy = (A) Proxy.newProxyInstance(A.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { A.class }, new ProxyOfA(proxy));

    //invoke
    proxyOfb.doit();
    proxyOfproxy.doit();
}
}
```

This will print

```
I am a B
Proxy of Proxy invoked
I am a Proxy
Proxy of Proxy invoked
```

Answer (score 0):

> what happens when the instance is a proxied one, and the method is running though an invocation handler?

There is no difference.  The Proxy *must* implement all the methods in your `interface`

> Then the instance object Class here has not the method and I can not get it and invoke it.

The InvocationHandler does, but the Proxy does.  The proxy calls the handler with the method from the interface it implements.

> is there any way to invoke a method by its name on an instance without having to retrieve the method from the class first?

You shouldn't have to tried Proxy(s) any differently.